# Count if function not working properly in vba

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm having some trouble getting my macro to use a countif funtion to display the frequency of scores in a given cell.  This is part of a larger macro that I am currently working on to generate a report out of a given set of exported data.

When I try to run the code, it returns all zeros in the cells I have specified even though there is data in there that matches my criteria.

Please feel free if you like to critique this code as I am just starting out in programming and wanting to learn as much as possible.

Thanks in advance!

Here is a copy of the code:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws_raw As Worksheet
Dim ws_rpt As Worksheet

Set ws_raw = Sheets("Raw Data")
Set ws_rpt = Sheets("Report")

If ws_raw.Range("H2") <> "" Then

    i = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("S2:CCC2"), "5")
    ws_raw.Range("I2").Value = i

    i = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("S2:CCC2"), "6")
    ws_raw.Range("J2").Value = i

    i = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("S2:CCC2"), "7")
    ws_raw.Range("K2").Value = i

    i = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("S2:CCC2"), "8")
    ws_raw.Range("L2").Value = i

Else

End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it as,

```
i = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("S2:CCC2"), 5)
```

Text-that-looks-like-a-number is not the same thing as a number; e.g. `5<>"5"`.

On a related note, explicitly referencing the [.Parent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980.aspx) worksheet is widely considered 'best practise'. A [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) not only cleans up your code but speeds it up. I also prefer using the [Excel Application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx) over the  of the [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) as any error can be returned to a variant.

```
Dim i As Variant
Dim ws_raw As Worksheet, ws_rpt As Worksheet

Set ws_raw = Sheets("Raw Data")
Set ws_rpt = Sheets("Report")

With ws_rpt
    If ws_raw.Range("H2") <> "" Then
        i = Application.CountIf(.Range("S2:CCC2"), 5)
        ws_raw.Range("I2").Value = i

        i = Application.CountIf(.Range("S2:CCC2"), 6)
        ws_raw.Range("J2").Value = i

        i = Application.CountIf(.Range("S2:CCC2"), 7)
        ws_raw.Range("K2").Value = i

        i = Application.CountIf(.Range("S2:CCC2"), 8)
        ws_raw.Range("L2").Value = i
    Else

    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You've the numbers you're counting converted to text by putting them in double-quotation marks - try this:

```
i = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("S2:CCC2"), 5)
ws_raw.Range("I2").Value = i


i = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("S2:CCC2"), 6)
ws_raw.Range("J2").Value = i


i = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("S2:CCC2"), 7)
ws_raw.Range("K2").Value = i


i = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("S2:CCC2"), 8)
ws_raw.Range("L2").Value = i
```